# TextField is overlapped by keyboard in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `TextField` in column with `verticalScroll()`.
When adding a large number of characters, the textfield size goes beyond the keyboard and I stop seeing what I am typing
I tried to use [this](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/) lib, but that's doesn't help

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [`BringIntoViewRequester`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/relocation/BringIntoViewRequester) in your `TextField`.

```kotlin
var state by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val bringIntoViewRequester = remember {
    BringIntoViewRequester()
}

TextField(
    value = state,
    onValueChange = { text ->
        state = text
        // This will cause the TextField be repositioned on the screen
        // while you're typing
        coroutineScope.launch {
            bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
        .onFocusChanged {
            if (it.isFocused) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    delay(400) // delay to way the keyboard shows up
                    bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                }
            }
        },
)
```

See the complete sample [here](https://github.com/nglauber/JetpackComposePlayground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/nglauber/jetpackcomposeplayground/screens/FocusRequesterScreen.kt).

Comment: Thank you, that delay statement fixed some weird behavior i kept seeing

Comment: Why do we need delay ?

Answer (score -2):

you can add `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:maxLines="1"` or whatever lines you want, in your text xml hope it would be helpful.

Comment: I use compose, compose is working without xml :)